# ec2: cannot open port 5080 on windows instance

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, firewall, red5, windows-firewall

I'm pretty new with ec2, firewall settings etc, so I might be missing something obvious, but:

- I've created a 'getting started with windows' instance
- with a security group that has 5080 specified
- and is associated with an elastic ip

On the instance I have a red5 server running. when I run the server it on 127.0.0.1:5080, i can access it from a browser on  that instance, so I know the server works.

When I run it on the elastic IP however, I can't connect to it, neither from within the instance nor from outside.

when I run telnet 75.101.147.86 5080 from the outside world i get 'connection refused'

**Any** clues on how to debug this would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the AWS management console.

1 goto **Amazon EC2** tab

2 Click on **Instances** and note the **Security Group Name** from the **Security Group** column for the instance you want to open it for.

3 Click on the link **Security Groups**

4 Click on the **Security Group Name** from step 2.

5 You should see a dropdown that says **SSH**, click it and select **Custom..**

6 Enter:

> ```
>  Protocol                  TCP
>  From Port                 5080
>  To Port                   5080
>  Source (IP or Group)      0.0.0.0/0       -- NOTE 1
> ```

7 Click Save.

If you need UDP also, then repeat using Protocol UDP in step 6.

NOTE 1: Read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing for more info... but don't try to limit the subnet until you have it working for the world.

If it doesn't work after that then you may have a firewall on the instance.  I'm more of an ubuntu guy, but try this : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-linux-firewall-under-centos-rhel-fedora/ for RedHat

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this problem to change the default port at ../conf/red5.properties to any other port. I changed it to 5081 and it works.