# running nodejs on amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, port, firewall

I am trying to run a nodeJS server on an Amazon EC2 instance but I cannot access it in public.

I have read several SO questions about this and also some blogs posts but no solution works for me.
This is my server config:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Simple server\n');
}).listen(4444);
console.log('Server running');
```

This is the output of `iptables -l`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4444
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:4444

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:4444
```

And the port `4444` is also added on the instance's security group.

After the server has started, running `curl localhost:4444` echoes the expected "Simple Server".
But I am not able to connect to the public DNS / IP address.

Do you know which setting is still missing?

Comment: Apart from this you have to add the port in security settings. See a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955910/ec2-cannot-open-port-5080-on-windows-instance

Comment: As I already wrote, the port is added to the instance's security group

Comment: Already added in the aws security console from the amazon account associated with ec2 instance ?

Comment: yes. i did this. TCP port 4444 is allowed for 0.0.0.0/0